# Autre chose vs Une autre chose

Tags: expressions

I was wondering if there is any difference between using "autre chose" and "une autre chose" for example in the sentence below:

Julie trouve que Paris est la ville parfaite. Une autre chose/autre chose parfaite est son petit ami Juan...

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Autre chose parfaite...* is possible but more on the literary side. I would remove the verb if I had to use it:

> Autre chose parfaite : son petit ami Juan.

Another issue is Juan is not a *chose* in the first place. We can still use it in a figurative way but it would be slightly jocular (maybe not an issue given the context).

Here is another suggestion:

> *Julie trouve que Paris est la ville parfaite. Parfait est aussi son petit ami Juan...*

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

*"**Une** autre chose parfaite est son petit ami Juan"*

But you cannot say:

*"Autre chose parfaite est son petit ami Juan"*

The explanation is that "autre chose" means "*something else*" meanwhile "une autre chose" means "*one more thing*".

Answer (score -1):

No, you say the same thing; however, your formulation is not proper; the two ideas are very loosely connected. Here are some possibilities without changing the order of the elements of the sentence but with some short additions so as to articulate the text a little better.

- Julie trouve que Paris est la ville parfaite. Une autre chose parfaite **qu'elle y trouve** c'est son petit ami Juan...
- Julie trouve que Paris est la ville parfaite. Autre chose **de** parfaite **pour elle dans cette ville**, c'est son petit ami Juan...
- Julie trouve que Paris est la ville parfaite. **Elle y trouve aussi** une autre chose parfaite,  c'est son petit ami Juan...